# Why should we separate DataSet code from DataAccess code?

Tags: c#, wcf, n-tier-architecture, dataset-designer

I've been converting my WinForm application using a tiered approach following this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384570.aspx

In the article, it recommends creating two separate class libraries, one for the typed DataSet class and one for DataAccess. I figured these two entities are fairly coupled logically, so why divide them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be able to reference your strongly typed data model without referencing any of the lower-level data access APIs. Your consuming code shouldn't have any awareness of where your data model originates from. You might want to use your data model in your UI layer. Your UI layer just needs to know about the model, not how the model is populated with data.

Comment: In addition to making the data layer easily replaceable, this approach allows you to write unit tests without involving the database. You could for example, create a simple mockup that would provide data and populate the data classes for testing purposes.

Comment: Very true. I didn't want to bring unit testing into it, but that's a good point.

Comment: Unit testing is the most frequently-mentioned bonus of an easily-replaceable data layer, but it's worth remembering the other benefits. I think a lot of developers underestimate the usefulness of being able to switch to a different data storage method without rewriting huge amounts of code. You could move from a server with MSSQL to one that only supports Oracle, or you could make an offline version that uses local storage, or XML files, or whatever you fancy.